# Why BasicAuthenticationFilter in spring security matches only username and not the password

Tags: spring-security

BasicAuthenticationFilter  while checking for existing authentication matches based on the username only. so if incoming request send correct username and incorrect password , the user is still considered already authenticated. Is this a desired behavior ? doesnt seem correct to me .any views ?

////////////////////

```
private boolean authenticationIsRequired(String username) {
        // Only reauthenticate if username doesn't match SecurityContextHolder and user
        // isn't authenticated
        // (see SEC-53)
        Authentication existingAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();

        if (existingAuth == null || !existingAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Limit username comparison to providers which use usernames (ie
        // UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)
        // (see SEC-348)

        if (existingAuth instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                && !existingAuth.getName().equals(username)) {
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it looks in SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); it means that the client already has the JSESSION cookie, so it has been already authenticated with username and password.

Checking password one more time will make this method worthless as it lead to redo all the authentication process (retrieving password from database, compare it...) and I guess it has been written to avoid it. Besides password is not stored in SecurityContextHolder context

A potential security breach could occur on CRSF attack but spring-security provides protection against this one. see [spring-security csrf](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I checked the same.I was using Postman to test REST APIs and expected 401 if i pass wrong password with the same user . As i had earlier provided correct password in earlier test request the new request with wrong pwd also passed.

Comment: @dev.K few months ago I wrote a post about saml authentication and jwt authentication for REST API. Saml is not relevant for you here, but you can give a look to the jwt part : https://www.sylvainlemoine.com/2016/06/06/spring-saml2.0-websso-and-jwt-for-mobile-api/ . Besides the spring-security official documentation is a must-read.

Comment: @dev.K as stated by dur, you can set the security to disable stateful session and csrf e.g:   http                 .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable()

Comment: Thanks  slemoine and dur for the explanation, With the mentioned configuration got the expected behavior, tested through postman.