# Spring boot WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter basic authentication user password validation issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm writing a simple REST API using Spring Boot and I want to enable basic authentication. Therefore I have used the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as shown below. For simplicity, I just want to check only the password (pwd123) and allow any user to log in. Please refer to the code below.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                if (authentication == null || authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
                }
                if (authentication.getCredentials().equals("pwd123")) {
                    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(),
                            authentication.getCredentials().toString(),
                            Collections.emptyList());
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Assume user_A has accessed the REST API with a valid password, i.e pwd123, and then do the send API call with a wrong password. However the user is allowed to access the API which is the problem.

When I do the debugging I realized that **authenticationIsRequired** function in **BasicAuthenticationFilter** class which is in Spring Security, returns false in such scenario. Please refer that code.

```
    private boolean authenticationIsRequired(String username) {
    // Only reauthenticate if username doesn't match SecurityContextHolder and user
    // isn't authenticated (see SEC-53)
    Authentication existingAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (existingAuth == null || !existingAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }
    // Limit username comparison to providers which use usernames (ie
    // UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) (see SEC-348)
    if (existingAuth instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken && !existingAuth.getName().equals(username)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle unusual condition where an AnonymousAuthenticationToken is already
    // present. This shouldn't happen very often, as BasicProcessingFitler is meant to
    // be earlier in the filter chain than AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.
    // Nevertheless, presence of both an AnonymousAuthenticationToken together with a
    // BASIC authentication request header should indicate reauthentication using the
    // BASIC protocol is desirable. This behaviour is also consistent with that
    // provided by form and digest, both of which force re-authentication if the
    // respective header is detected (and in doing so replace/ any existing
    // AnonymousAuthenticationToken). See SEC-610.
    return (existingAuth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken);
}
```

Please let me know what is missing in my implementation

Comment: The problem with InMemoryUserDetailManager is, that we have to supply all the user names and passwords. In my case user authentication should be done by a separate third party system

Comment: I mean for this one simple test you try to do. You are using 1 set of credentials only but create a custom `AuthenticationProvider` instead of using the out-of-the-box  in-mem authentication provider. No need to supply all credentials for one test. I'm not suggesting your approach is wrong, but you better know the ins and outs of Spring Security then and how all components work together if you move away from what is provided out of the box.

Comment: I developed this simple test with the intention of using it in our system where we have to use a thrid party Authentication System. For that we have to plug a Authentication Provider. Therefore even if this problem gets resolved from InMemoryUserDetailsManager, it does not help in long run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments and answers, even if you use the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`  the problem does not get resolved, which means, once the user is authenticated with the correct user name and password, his password is not validated in the subsequent REST API calls,i.e. can use any password. This is because of the functionality in `BasicAuthenticationFilter` class where it skips users who are having a valid JSESSION cookie.

To fix the issue, we should configure http to create state-less sessions via
`http .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()`

in `configure` function of the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Please refer [Why BasicAuthenticationFilter in spring security matches only username and not the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895133/why-basicauthenticationfilter-in-spring-security-matches-only-username-and-not-t)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, instead of providing a custom `AuthenticationProvider` you can try providing a custom `UserDetailsService`. Here's the complete configuration:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (username) -> new User(username, "{noop}pwd123", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
    }

}
```

When you evolve to looking up the user via a third-party service, you can add the code to do this in the custom `UserDetailsService` (a lambda function or an actual class that implements the interface) and continue returning a `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`.

**Note:** I don't actually recommend plain-text passwords in production. You would replace `{noop}pwd123` with something like `{bcrypt}<bcrypt encoded password here>`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, the authentication has to be done via a third party system, which means, I don't have the access to users or their passwords in the system. When a REST Api is called, I have to call that third-party system to get the request authenticated, therefore your answer or the answer suggested by Nico Van Belle does not work for me. I have to use the Authentication provider

Comment: Apologies, that was not 100% clear and was not detailed in your original post. If you take a look at `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and base class, you will see a variety of concerns you have to account for when implementing a username/password authentication provider, third party or not. One example is a timing attack on passwords to find non-existing users. Another is erasing credentials once authentication is complete (success or failure). A third would be upgrading password encoding schemes. The list goes on. At this point, you may want to strongly consider OAuth instead.